# How to access the member of the class after initialization?

Tags: javascript, web, client, openlayers

I create this class using pure javascript:

```
var SelectFeature = /*@__PURE__*/(function (Select) {
    function SelectFeature() {
        Select.call(this, {
            condition: ol.events.condition.click
        });
    }

    this.on('select', function (e) {
        //some logic
    });

    if (Select) SelectFeature.__proto__ = Select;
    SelectFeature.prototype = Object.create(Select && Select.prototype);
    SelectFeature.prototype.constructor = Select;

    return SelectFeature;
}(ol.interaction.Select));
```

as you can see I pass ol.interaction.Select as a parameter to the class and using Select.call() the method in SelectFeature as a constructor.

Here is a description of ol.interaction.Select class.

The ol.interaction.Select class has a member who is called `on()`. I try to access this method like this in the example above:

```
this.on('select', function (e) {
        //some logic
})
```

but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.on is not a function
```

My question is how can I access the on the member of the ol.interaction.Select class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` has no definition outside of the `SelectFeature` function.
So you need to call `this.on` inside the `SelectFeature` function.
In order to do that you need to set the `on` function *inside* the `SelectFeature` function:

```js
var SelectFeature = /*@__PURE__*/(function (Select) {
    function SelectFeature() {
        Select.call(this, {
            condition: ol.events.condition.click
        });
        this.on = Select.prototype.on; // This gets Select's on method and gives it to `this`
        this.on('select', function (e) {
           //some logic
         });
    }

    if (Select) SelectFeature.__proto__ = Select;
    SelectFeature.prototype = Object.create(Select && Select.prototype);
    SelectFeature.prototype.constructor = Select;

    return SelectFeature;
}(ol.interaction.Select));
```

Comment: N8, thanks for the post. Can you please explain this row:  this.on = Select.prototype.on;
Why I have to access on function with help of prototype?

Comment: When you initiate an object of the `Select` class, it gets the method `on` from `Select.prototype`. So in order to give your object the `on` method during initialization, you need to pull the `on` method out of where it originally resides: `Select.prototype`.